# Javascript QuickSort implementation bugs

Tags: javascript, algorithm, quicksort

So this was my initial attempt at implementing quickSort in order to understand the algorithm better, and it seems to work fine, but the second I change to a different test case, it seems to break and doesn't completely sort. Im not sure where the problem is within the code, and I've tried googling and tried changing the most outer while loop within hoarePartition to while(left < right), but it doesnt seem to fully sort the array either.

Any suggestions on how I could fix the program below?
Thanks

```js
var arr = [30, 291, 59323, 2931, 2935023, 1923, 104, 29, 45, 23, 1, 59303, 2, 5, 9, 20, 11, 16];

console.log(arr);

var quickSort = function(arr, left, right) {
  left = left || 0;
  right = right || arr.length - 1;
  
  var pivot = hoarePartition(arr, left, right);
  
  if (left < pivot - 1) {
    quickSort(arr, left, pivot -1);
  } 
  if (right > pivot) {
    quickSort(arr, pivot, right);
  }

  return arr;
}

var sortedArr = quickSort(arr);
console.log(sortedArr);

/////////////////
function hoarePartition(arr, left, right) {
  var pivot = Math.floor((left + right) / 2);
  while (left <= right) {
    while (arr[left] < arr[pivot]) {
      left++;
    }
    while (arr[right] > arr[pivot]) {
      right--;
    }
    if (left <= right) {
      //swap
      var temp = arr[left];
      arr[left] = arr[right];
      arr[right] = temp;

      left++;
      right--;
    }
  }
  return left;
}
```

Comment: What am I missing if I say "What's wrong with `Array.sort()`"? Because I must miss something.

Comment: What is this line intended to do? `right = right || arr.length - 1;`

Comment: Do you have an example of a test case where this breaks?

Comment: @MBo that line will set `right` to the argument if it is not undefined, other wise `right` is the last index of the array.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I have tried random test cases with change of size, values of array elements such as:  var arr = [30, 291, 59323, 2931, 2935023, 1923, 104, 29, 45, 23, 1, 59303, 2, 123382, 9, 20, 11, 16]; and <--- this seems to be return unsorted